# How can I set focus through Word vba range.find

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am writing a macro in Word, for replacing some text with a mapped definition.

I want to give the user the option to give confirmation for each replace, just like the default Find & Replace.

How can I set focus on the text that is found?
How can the particular section be scrolled into view?

I need to use custom VBA code(rather than default Find & Replace) as I have to process the document after reading in the mappings.

I am already able to replace the text, and also show the alerts to the user.
However, I want to put the focus on the text while showing the alert.

Current code:

```
Do While myRange.Find.Execute( _
            FindText:=dict.Items()(i) & " (" & Word & ")", _
            MatchCase:=False, _
            MatchWholeWord:=True _
            )                    
    myRange.Select                        
    If MsgBox("Replace '" & myRange.Find.Text & "' with '" & Word & "'?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        myRange.Text = Word
    End If

    myRange.Start = myRange.Start + Len(myRange.Find.Text)
    myRange.End = cached
Loop
```

p.s. I have a custom form/dialog open, from which the macro is being run;
so the text is behind the dialog.

**EDIT:** Based on Jay's response, I again checked the behavior of the Find & Replace dialog. The dialog gets moved based on the location of the text. Can I achieve the same when I have a form and a confirmation dialog over the text?

Comment: Show us what you've tried and explain HOW it's not working for you. And why would you not use Word's built-in dialog box for this?

Answer (score 1):

The statement myRange.Select that's already in your code puts the Selection on the found text, and scrolls it into view if it's offscreen. That won't help, though, if the Selection is hidden behind a custom form (userform?) or the message box. You may be able to move the form out of the way, if you can figure out where the Selection is with respect to the screen coordinates.